# Matlab symbolic sum and product get stuck

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have the following equations that I want to plot in Matlab

[image]

I declare equation (1) in matlab as follows (no problems):

```
function [Dg]=Dnum(X,x,y,M)

chi=exp(-2*X); 
syms l x y 
%---- 
F1= matlabFunction(...
    ((1-chi)/(1-1/M))*symsum(...
    l^2*((1+chi^l)/(1-chi^l))*gamma(x+1)^2*gamma(y+1)^2/(gamma(x+1+l)...
    *gamma(x+1-l)*gamma(y+1+l)*gamma(y+1-l)),l,1,M...
    )...
    );
%---- 
Dg=F1(x,y);

end
```

Then, I declare equation (2) in a similar fashion:

```
function [Ds]=Dsnum(X,x,y,M)

chi=exp(-2*X); 
syms k l x y  %-- k->j 
%---- 
F1= matlabFunction(...
    ((1-chi)/(1-1/M))*symsum(...
    (l+1)^2*((1+chi^(l+1))/(1-chi^(l-1)))*...
    symprod((x-k/M)*(y-k/M)/(x+(k+1)/M)/(y+(k+1)/M),k,0,l)...
    ,l,0,M...
    )...
    );
%---- ASEP diffusion evaluation
Ds=F1(x,y);

end
```

However, this time matlab is unable to create the function. Doing things one step at the time. It looks like Matlab cannot compute the `symsum` if it includes a `symprod`.

Is there a better to define this type of function? I am unsure if it is possible to directly define this as function handle `Ds = @(x,y) (some definition)`. Both, x and y are vectors of integers, and any other parameter in the equation are single value.

Comment: Currently using Matlab 2018a and 2021a, the same result in both versions

Comment: Don't use `syms`. There's also no need to use an anonymous function (what you call "function handle"). Just do the arithmetic directly, numerically. Use a `for` loop to do the summation and the product. Keep it simple.

Comment: What error do you get? Please include it in the Q and which line it occurs on. If you go to Editor tab > Run > Pause on Errors you will be able to see the state of the variables when the error occurs.

Comment: Also as per what @Cris said - your usage of symbolic variables and function handles is very unusual. (i) Why are `x` and `y` inputs into your functions when they are immediately overwritten as symbolic variables? (ii) do you want the output of Dnum to be the function itself - or the function evaluated at particular values of `x` and `y`?